# Round DateTime using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to round a DateTime feature such a way that it gets converted to the start value of every 10 minute time interval. Example below shows the desired result:

```
     Actual Time              |        Round Time(within 10 min interval)


  2016-01-01 05:47:46                      2016-01-01 05:40:00
  2016-01-01 05:49:58                      2016-01-01 05:40:00
  2016-01-01 05:50:01                      2016-01-01 05:50:00
  2016-01-01 05:59:58                      2016-01-01 05:50:00
```

Code below, rounds it to nearest 10 minute interval instead of always giving the floor value.

```
df['DateTime'].agg(lambda x : x.round('10min'))
```

It rounds the DateTime Feature to the nearest value.

```
   Actual Time              |        Round Time(within 10 min interval)

  2016-01-01 05:47:46                      2016-01-01 05:50:00
  2016-01-01 05:49:58                      2016-01-01 05:50:00
  2016-01-01 05:50:01                      2016-01-01 05:50:00
  2016-01-01 05:59:58                      2016-01-01 06:00:00
```

Round time such a way that it falls near the floor value.

Comment: Not clear, kindly be more clear in your post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['Round Time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.floor('10min')
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Thank you. What kinf of error was raised?

Comment: sure, here is error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - You need convert column to datetimes in first step.